# set running process on bottom

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm new to C++ just started to learn and I'm trying to change the appearance of a running process for example "Calculator" to be always on bottom/on desktop but with no successes.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void set_to_bg() {
    LPCSTR app_name = "Calculator";
    HWND hWnd = FindWindowA(0, (app_name));
    HWND ProgmanHwnd = FindWindow(_T("Progman"), _T("Program Manager"));
    SetParent(hWnd, ProgmanHwnd);
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
}

int main()
{
    set_to_bg();

    return 0;
}
```

What Happens is that the "Calculator" window disappears.
I'm using Spy++ to monitor windows and I'v noticed that the "Calculator" is parented to "Program Manager" but it doesn't shows it.
if I omit the `"SetParent(hWnd, ProgmanHwnd);"` the "Calculator" is shown and sets to bottom.
When I open a folder or some other app they overlap the "Calculator" which is a good result but if I click the "Calculator" then it losses its "OnBottom" property and overlaps all the other folders or apps that opened.

Any ideas, code snippets, guidance would be very appreciated!

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683)

Answer (score 1):

SHELLDLL_DefView which contains the desktop icons listview is a child of the Progman window and covers the entire desktop and you need to be a child of the listview if you want to be "stuck" to the desktop but this is a hack and relies on internal shell details.

`HWND_BOTTOM` is not a property, it just tells `SetWindowPos` to put the window at the bottom of the z-order right now but it does not get stuck there, it is still a normal window. There is a internal "bottom most" property in the window manager but you cannot use it in your own applications, only the shell desktop icon window can use this internal style.

You can take a look at [Rainlendar](http://www.ipi.fi/~rainy/legacy.html) and other open source gadget applications to see how they do it but there is no perfect solution. You have to consider the "[what if](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101125-00/?p=12203) [two applications did this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)" scenario.